# JavaScript return a default value

Tags: javascript, function

I want to make a library of functions like this (similar to what jquery is doing)

```
var myLib = function (idOfAnElement){
  var myElement = document.getElementById(idOfAnElement);
  return{
    getHeight: function (){
      return myElement.style.height;
    },
    getWidth: function (){
      return myElement.style.width;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to return

```
myElement
```

by default, if there is no other function called like

```
myLib('myId').getHeight; // Returns Height
myLib('myId')            // Is supposed to return the HTML-Element with id = 'myId'
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Create a *privileged* method returning the value of *private* `myElement` property itself

```
var myLib = function (idOfAnElement){
  var myElement = document.getElementById(idOfAnElement);

  return{
    getHeight: function (){
      return myElement.style.height;
    },
    getWidth: function (){
      return myElement.style.width;
    },
    getElement: function() {
      return myElement;
    }
  }
}

myLib('myId').getElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved simply by adding the methods you want to the element object,

Javascript allows easy adding methods to existing objects, even the `this` pointer will point to the bound object.

```
var myLib = function (idOfAnElement){
  var myElement = document.getElementById(idOfAnElement);
  myElement.getHeight: function (){
      return this.style.height;
  }
  myElement.getWidth: function (){
      return this.style.width;
  }
  return myElement;
}
```

Note: While it works, I wouldn't recommend it.
You need to take care not to overwrite existing methods/fields and if multiple libraries will take the same approach a collision is likely.

And this is NOT what jQuery is doing: they create a wrapper object. To get the element from jQuery you need to use `[0]` for example `$('#myEl')[0]`.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  if so you can mark the question as answered (click the check mark next the answer of your choice), if not you can ask a followup question and we'll explain.